# laravel-with-docker-example project fails to build

Tags: docker

I am trying to run below project with docker.

https://github.com/kyleferguson/laravel-with-docker-example

which has the below docker file.

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

When i run the "docker-compose up" after running the "composer install".

I get below errors.

---

> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install
> -y libmcrypt-dev mariadb-client     && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql]: exit code: 1 ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build

Any idea on how to fix this?

Note:
**I already tried replacing mariadb-client with mysql-client and default-my-client, still the same issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems here, which is why switching to mariadb didn't work on its own.

One way to make it more clear what the problem is, is to bash into a container created from your base image and run the commands manually.

```
docker run -it php:7-fpm bash
```

From there if you run each install individually you'll see where you are failing:

```
# apt-get install -y mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-client
```

Either add a repo that provides mysql, or use mariadb.

```
# docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
error: /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt does not exist
```

mcrypt was removed in php 7.2 so you'll need to use pecl to install it, if you really need it.

Unless you're running a very old version of Laravel, you shouldn't need mcrypt.